# Are there languages with tense that lack a pluperfect?

Tags: grammar, tense

This is something I've been thinking about. It would be rather hard to tell a story without using a pluperfect. I know there are languages that lack tense, like Chinese, but what about languages that do have tense systems? Japanese for instance has pretty much just past and non-past. What kind of structure would they use where we would use a pluperfect?

I should note that the only languages I'm deeply familiar with are English (my native language) and German (which does have a pluperfect, formed the same way we form one in English). I did study Japanese for a few years when I was younger and into anime, but I never really got far into it. I only know the basics of the grammar.

Comment: Have you done some initial research? For example, in Slavic languages the Pluperfect [is lost or very rare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluperfect#Slavic_languages).

Comment: I was also interesting in knowing what languages do when they lack it. I don't believe I've ever heard of Japanese having one. But I could be wrong. LIke I said, I only know the grammar on a beginner level.

Comment: In Russian, for example, it is very occasionaly used (mostly in written language) and not everyone even understands this is plueperfect, like: ”On bylo vstal iz-za stola, no rešil, čto lučše rešit' zadaču sejčas“ (He first had stood up but then decided it was better to finish the task). Instead, you can use simple past tense (sequencing your verbs right), adverbials that structure the discourse (before/after etc.) I do not feel like I lack plueperfect to fully express myself.

Comment: Lots of languages have tense but lack a pluperfect. Modern Hebrew for example has only three tenses, past, present, and future.

Comment: @gleisner_robot Isn't aspect (perfective/imperfective) also involved in Russian? That could make things different regarding the lack of some tenses (which in Western European languages tend to be mixtures of tense and aspect).

Comment: What does it mean, to "have  a pluperfect"? Evidently every language must have a way to express the idea that a fact was already past in the time the narrative refers to; some languages have a synthetic way to express it, others need verbal phrases. For instance, Standard Portuguese "has" a pluperfect: *João **terminara** seu mestrado quando decidiu emigrar para a Tunísia*; English "has not": *John **had finished** his master's degree when he decided to emigrate to Tunisia*. But both languages can easily express the idea.

Comment: @pablodf76 Yes, you are right. Russian verbal system is characterized by an intertwining of tense and aspect, and in some cases a specific combination of verbs may signal that some action took place either simultaneously or before another action in the past. For example, in indirect speech:
_On skazal, čto jest (Present, imperfective) jabloko_ (He told he was eating an apple)
_On skazal, čto sjel (Past, perfective) jabloko_ (He told he had eaten an apple)

Answer (score 1):

E.g. Czech and other Slavic languages. Pluperfect in English is very often used in indirect speech where there is no present, past or future but rather simultaneity, "previousness" and  "consecutiveness", for which English uses simple past, pluperfect and "conditional" (or future past - past tense of the auxiliary verb *will*) respectively, while Czech would use typically the present tense for simultaneous action, past tense for previous action and future tense for following action as it is clear that the temporal reference point of the clause is not "now" (time of the current utterance) but rather as "then" (time of the utterance the main clause is talking about).

e.g.:

> Mother **said** that children **were** asleep. (past - past:
>   simultaneous)
>
> Matka **řekla**, že děti **spí**. (past - present: simultaneous)
>
> Mother **said** that children **would** fall asleep. (past - future
>   past: following)
>
> Matka **řekla**, že děti **usnou**. (past - future: following)